# Validate Form Data With PHP - w3schools

Tags: php

Hy!

So I'm learning PHP on w3schools and I came across this site: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp 
At the end of the page there's a 2. point that says you should

> "Remove backslashes () from the user input data (with the PHP
>   stripslashes() function)"

I don't understand what's the purpose of that. May somebody please explain?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hy to you too! Now, first and the most important thing of your future life as a programmer - **never, ever go back to w3schools again**. Ever. Consider it as a plague bearing infected zombie. As for WHY they remove backslash - it's because they still live in 1999 when that might have been a problem. In today's day and year, we are not dumb and we use proper tools when interacting with databases and we don't have to severely cripple the data we receive from our users if we use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: If w3schools.com is as bad as you say it is then which site do you recommend I should be learning from?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive guide and say that a particular resource is above peer, but [php the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) seems ok. What you have to realize is that w3schools is ok to give you a push into programming, but that site is made to generate income and it contains so many mistakes, bad practices and it generally teaches you wrong things in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit to removing quotations and backslashes is to prevent either deliberate or unintended SQL injection.

Not sure what mySQL injection is?

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Or use something like PDO where you don't have to worry about it at all :)

Comment: Indeed, however I would assume he is using raw queries if he is reading from W3schools :P.

Comment: Not only SQL injection but javascript injection as well.  Overall you want to preform what's called data santization to remove anything that can potentially harm your server or your users. Worth skimming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection